# Wordpress functions.php has a parse error

Tags: php, wordpress

Hi I ran into a prob while setting up the functions.php file for Wordpress. My localhost server is showing this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF) in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wdnomads-wp/wp-content/themes/womendigitalnomads/functions.php on line 3

I've tried googling and pasting Wordpress' own code, but the error still exists. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
<? php

    if ( ! isset( $content_width ) ) {
    $content_width = 660;
}
```

Comment: `<?php` not `<? php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<? php` should be `<?php`.

Comment: Thanks that worked, but now it shows I have an error with another line of code: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')'    I've tried looking for an extra ' but can't find it. Can you help? Thank you!    
        wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrapjs', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'), true );
        
    }

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts'; 'womendig_scripts');

Answer (score 2):

What exactly is your question?

Your formatting should have no space before `php`

Answer (score 0):

Try out this, just replace your code with following code :-

```
function prefix_content_width() {
    $GLOBALS['content_width'] = apply_filters( 'prefix_content_width', 660 );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'prefix_content_width', 0 );
```